# Select data from sqlite3 before or after a certain date using Typeorm

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, sqlite, typeorm

I want to **select** the data before or after a certain date in `sqlite` using `Typeorm` where date is in `milliseconds`.

Here is my `Query Builder`:

```
  const qb = getConnection()
    .getRepository(Post)
    .createQueryBuilder('p')
    .where('createdAt < :cursor', {
       cursor: "1624809058000"
     })
    .getMany()
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to pass the date in this format: `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss.l"` Example: `"2000-01-01 00:00:00.000"` 
So, we have to convert the date in this format.

1. First solution

```
  const chars = { T: ' ', Z: '' }
  const dateInMilliseconds = "1624809058000"
  const qb = getConnection()
    .getRepository(Post)
    .createQueryBuilder('p')
    .where('createdAt < :cursor', {
       cursor: new Date(parseInt(dateInMilliseconds))
         .toISOString()
         .replace(/[TZ]/g, ch => chars[ch])
     })
    .getMany()
```

2. Second solution

```
import { LessThan, MoreThan } from 'typeorm'
import { format } from 'date-fns'

// TypeORM Query Operators
const MoreThanDate = (date: Date) => MoreThan(format(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'))
const LessThanDate = (date: Date) => LessThan(format(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'))

const dateInMilliseconds = "1624809058000"
const posts = await Post.find({
    createdAt: MoreThanDate(new Date(dateInMilliseconds))
})
```

3. Third solution

```
import { Between } from 'typeorm';
import { addYears, subYears } from 'date-fns';

// TypeORM Query Operators
const MoreThanDate = (date: Date) => Between(date, addYears(date, 100));
const LessThanDate = (date: Date) => Between(subYears(date, 100), date);

const dateInMilliseconds = "1624809058000"
const posts = await Post.find({
  where: {
    createdAt: MoreThanDate(new Date(dateInMillisecons)),
  },
});
```